# Using component prop inside function body of reselect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

Honestly, after hours of research, I totally don't understand reselect, so I just ask why I need it, and if it can help.

> Selectors are efficient. A selector is not recomputed unless one of its arguments changes.

It's a bit unclear, what do we mean as `argument` here, but I assume that not the redux state, because otherwise there wouldn't be any point in reselect.

My goal is to not calculate the whole list every time something happens, because it can contain thousands of elements.

First question is that if for an example the value of `state["2"]` changes to 4 for an example, it will run through the whole list?

```
//for an example, in the next list, the key is the child,
//and the value is it's parent
const state = {
  1: 5,
  2: 5,
  3: 2,
  4: 1,
  5: 10,
  //...
  1000: 342
};

//and we have to find all children of a specific element,
//what we get from the component's own props

const getState = (
  state,
  props //okay, I can access it here
) => state;

const getChildren = createSelector(
  [getState],
  state => Object.keys(state).filter(child => {
    const parent = state[child];

    return parent === props.id //but I need it here
  })
);

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) = ({ children: getChildren(state, props) });
```

And the main question: how can I access the props inside the function body?

Comment: You already have perfect example how to achieve it and why here: https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#accessing-react-props-in-selectors Is this not enough?

Comment: Could you please specify where it shows how to access props inside function body?

Comment: "Accessing React Props in Selectors" 7th link in table of contents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `props` argument directly to the other selector `getChildren` and you don't need the first getState like this:

```
const getChildren = createSelector(
   [
      state => state,
      props => props
   ], (state, props) => {...}
```

About clarifying the use cases for reselect:
it *does* recompute if the state or the props changes (any argument indeed). So why using it? I use it for 2 reasons

1. you can combine parts of state coming from multiple reducers and build up what we can call a 'meta-reducer' and pass that to your component. In that way you place that code only in one place (the selector) and you can reuse it across different components. Imagine each reducer like a database table and the selector like a query result. You can query anything from your state and you want to keep the result cached for performance.
2. instead of running this logic on the `mapStateToProps` which is run every time that a component renders (no matter if the state has changed), you run it only 1 time per state change and you get the cached version if the component rerenders. This happens for example if a child component renders only because its parent rendered but the state portion related to its selector didn't change. So I like to use selectors all the times instead of accessing the redux state directly.

Comment: So if I use inside purecomponents, we can say that there's no difference between processing data simply in mapstatetoprops. Except, if I misunderstood something. Could you please confirm: if I have a selector on for an example state.list (long object), but state.name (string) changes, because state.list didn't changed, will it use the cached version, or will calculate it? Important: inside purecomponent, and state.list is an object

Comment: I think that the pure component does not rerender but mapState still runs because it is wrapping the component but I might be wrong on this. The best way to check this is to but a breakpoint (or wait for someone with a better knowledge).
Regarding the selector it runs if the ARGUMENTS of the function change. So if you pass the entire STATE it will recompute if state.name changes, but if you only pass state.list it will not recompute when state.name changes. That is why is better to pass only the relevant portion of the state as argument of a selector

Answer (score 2):

Here's the typical flow.

You'll have some `ConnectedComponent` that's hooked into `connect`, and its `mapStateToProps` calls out to a selector with both `state` and `ownProps`.

You have individual selectors for both the getting of `id` off of `props` and your objects from `state`.

**Using ConnectedComponent**

```
<span>
    <ConnectedComponent id="123" />
</span>
```

**mapStateToProps (ConnectedComponent)**

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {getMyObjectSelector} from './selectors';

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    myObject: getMyObjectSelector(state, ownProps)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component)
```

**selectors**

```
const getIdFromProps = (state, props) => props.id
const getMyObjectsFromState= state => state.myObjects;

export getMyObjectSelector = createSelector(
   getMyObjectsFromState,
   getIdFromProps,
   (objects, id) => objects[id]
);
```

**Component**

```
export const Component = ({myObject}) => (
   <span>
   // Do stuff
   </span>
)
```

Comment: How do I implement this in a stateless function where I have to use hooks (`useSelector`) and can't use the `mapStateToProps` because it is not classed based and still have access to the components props?

Comment: @EdwardBella I think you can use it in a similar way: `useSelector(state => getMyObjectSelector(state, props))`